# new Runnable() but no new thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I'm trying to understand the code [here](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/2.3/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) , specifically the anonymous class

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
   final long start = mStartTime;
   long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
   int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
   int minutes = seconds / 60;
   seconds     = seconds % 60;

   if (seconds < 10) {
       mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
   } else {
       mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);            
   }

   mHandler.postAtTime(this,
           start + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 1) * 1000));
   }
};
```

The article says

> The Handler runs the update code as a part of your main thread, avoiding the overhead of a second thread..

Shouldn't creating a new Runnable class make a new second thread? What is the purpose of the Runnable class here apart from being able to pass a Runnable class to postAtTime?

Thanks

Comment: No. Runnables are not `Thread`s. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`Runnable` is often used to provide the code that a thread should run, but `Runnable` itself has nothing to do with threads.  It's just an object with a `run()` method.

In Android, the `Handler` class can be used to ask the framework to run some code later on the *same* thread, rather than on a different one.  `Runnable` is used to provide the code that should run later.

Comment: "Runnable itself has nothing to do with threads" this is conceptually WRONG! Please read documentation. Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread. It is also confusing when Runnable is passed, but stuff happens in the same thread. Please read about "principle of least surprise".

Comment: @glaz666, the `Runnable` documentation talks about threads because they're the most *common* use of `Runnable`, but the interface is suitable for any kind of callback.  I think the Android `Handler`'s use of `Runnable` is entirely reasonable — it's better than defining a new Android-specific interface that's identical to `Runnable` but with a different name.

Comment: An example of "new Runnable()" without "extends Thread" nor "implements Runnable":
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java

Comment: @glaz666, I've never liked the wording in Runnable's javadoc (that you quoted earlier), and apparently the Java folks agreed that it was too narrow.  Notice how they improved the same wording in Callable's javadoc: "The Callable interface is similar to Runnable, in that both are designed for classes whose instances are potentially executed by another thread."

Answer (score 27):

If you want to create a new `Thread`...you can do something like this...

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { 
  // your code goes here... 
}});
```

Comment: Not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 17):

The `Runnable` interface is another way in which you can implement multi-threading other than extending the `Thread` class due to the fact that Java allows you to extend only one class.

You can however, use the [new Thread(Runnable runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) constructor, something like this:

```
private Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
   final long start = mStartTime;
   long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
   int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
   int minutes = seconds / 60;
   seconds     = seconds % 60;

   if (seconds < 10) {
       mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
   } else {
       mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);            
   }

   mHandler.postAtTime(this,
           start + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 1) * 1000));
   }
});

thread.start();
```

Comment: so does this example create a new thread or not, because you have used Thread but not called  start()..

Comment: @shishirgarg: This example creates a new Thread object. To execute it, simply call the `start()` method like so:  `thread.start()`. That should internally call the `run()` method (note, you should never call the `run()` method yourself) which kick starts the thread.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a thread just like this:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                       }
                    });
                thread.start();
```

Also, you can use Runnable, Asyntask, Timer, TimerTaks and AlarmManager to excecute Threads.

Comment: you can override the run() method of Thread. What's the benefit of creating the Runnable too?

Answer (score 7):

Runnable is just an interface, which provides the method run.
Threads are implementations and use Runnable to call the method run().

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't creating a new Runnable class make a new second thread?

No. new `Runnable` does not create second `Thread`.

> What is the purpose of the Runnable class here apart from being able to pass a Runnable class to postAtTime?

`Runnable` is posted to `Handler`. This task runs in the thread, which is associated with `Handler`.

If `Handler` is associated with UI Thread, `Runnable` runs in UI Thread.

If `Handler` is associated with other `HandlerThread`, Runnable runs in `HandlerThread`

---

To explicitly associate Handler to your MainThread ( UI Thread), write below code.

```
Handler  mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper();
```

If you write is as below, it uses HandlerThread Looper.

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
handlerThread.start();
Handler requestHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
```

---

Answer (score 0):

> Best and easy way is just pass argument and create instance and call
>   thread method

Call thread using create a thread object and send a runnable class object with parameter or **without parameter**  and start method of thread object.

In my condition I am sending parameter and I will use in run method.

> new Thread(new FCMThreadController("2", null, "3", "1")).start();

OR

> new Thread(new FCMThreadController()).start();

```
public class FCMThreadController implements Runnable {
private String type;
private List<UserDeviceModel> devices;
private String message;
private String id;


    public FCMThreadController(String type, List<UserDeviceModel> devices, String message, String id) {

        this.type = type;
        this.devices = devices;
        this.message = message;
        this.id = id;
    }



    public FCMThreadController( ) {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

A thread is something like some branch. Multi-branched means when there are at least two branches. If the branches are reduced, then the minimum remains one. This one is although like the branches removed, but in general we do not consider it branch.

Similarly when there are at least two threads we call it  multi-threaded program. If the threads are reduced, the minimum remains one. Hello program is a single threaded program, but no one needs to know multi-threading to write or run it.

In simple words when a program is not said to be having threads, it means that the program is not a multi-threaded program, more over in true sense it is a single threaded program, in which YOU CAN put your code as if it is multi-threaded.

Below a useless code is given, but it will suffice to do away with your some confusions about `Runnable`. It will print  "Hello World".

```
class NamedRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run() { // The run method prints a message to standard output.
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

    public static void main(String[]arg){ 
        NamedRunnable namedRunnable = new NamedRunnable( );
        namedRunnable.run();
    } 
}
```