# Can I change the text of a label from a Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel

I have another question for this forum. I am writing a small application with Java in which I have multiple Threads. I have two Threads that are in two different classes. I have one Thread (*thread1*) dedicated to defining all of the JFrame components. (JPanels, JButtons, ActionListeners, etc.) In another Thread, (*thread2*) I am checking for a variable (*v*) to equal a certain value. (*98*) When this variables does change to equal *98*, that **same thread** is supposed to update a JLabel. (Let's call this label *label* for now.) It does not. Is there something I am doing wrong. I have tried writing a method for the class - that declares all of the JFrame components - that changes the text of *label*, but when I call this method from *thread2* it does not update the label. I have tried calling a super class containing *thread1*, but that did not seem to make a difference. Also, I have been calling the *repaint()* method, but that does not seem to help.

Please let me know what I can do to update these JLabels from the two different Threads.

Thanks in advance,
  ~Rane

Code:

Class1:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel("V does not equal 98 Yet...");
Thread thread1 = new Thread(){

  public void run(){

    panel.add(label);
    frame.add(panel);
    System.out.println("Components added!");

  }
});

public void setLabelText(String text){
  label.setText(text);
}
```

Class1=2:

```
v = 0;
Thread thread2 = new Thread(){

  public void run(){

    while(v < 98){

      System.out.println("V equals -" + v + "-.");
      v ++;
    }
    Class1 otherClass = new Class1();
    otherClass.label.setText("V is now equal to: " + v);
    otherClass.repaint();
    otherClass.setLabelText("V is now equal to: " + v);
    otherClass.repaint();
  }
});
```

Comment: Swing is a single threaded framework, it is also NOT thread safe, this means that all creation, ulceration so and modifications to any UI should be done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. It also means y should not execute long running or blocking code within the context of the EDT as this will cause the program to appear as its hung (because it has). So the answer to your question is, NO, NEVER, EVER, should you be doing what your trying to do. Consider using a SwingWorker of using SwingUtilities.invokeLater to ensure that updates are synchronised back to the EDT...

Comment: Well said. Any thread can cause code to be executed in the AWT/ETD/Swing thread (all alternative names for the same) by `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

Comment: Remember, you shouldn't be doing it this way, but, you seem to be making two instances of Class1, the instance in thread 1 is not the same instance in thread 2, so changing one will have no effect on the other...

Comment: If you don't suggest I use Threads, how do you suggest that I update the JLabel? If JLabel is not Thread-safe, is there another similar GUI that you would recommend?

Comment: FYI, everything that your program does is "from a thread."  Even if you program is just a simple console app that does not create any new threads of its own, it will run in the JVM's "main" thread, and the JVM will have several other threads running to do things like garbage collection & I don't know what else.

Comment: Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: Again, the links are all here, you just have to read them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Swing is **not** thread-safe. I repeat: do not call any methods on Swing objects from any threads other than the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

If you are getting events from multiple different threads and you want to have them directly affect Swing objects, you should use:

```
// Note you must use final method arguments to be available inside an anonymous class
private void changeJLabel(final JLabel label, final String text) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      myLabel.setText(text);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @LifeH2O No, there's only one thread - the Event Dispatch Thread. This just schedules tasks for that thread to process.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029795/new-runnable-but-no-new-thread explains `new Runnable(){}`

Comment: Hi,
I have the same problem but can't make the String final. It changes quite often during the run. Any Ideas?

Comment: @DonDrenai Feel free to ask a separate question. Note that I am not saying the string should be final, just that it should be declared final **as a method argument** from your `updateJLabel` function or whatever. You can still call such a method with different strings at different times during your program.