# Add function as parameter and call them

Tags: java

i want to create an class which accept "function" and i can add there some method that i can call later. For example:

```
final Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();

wrapper.add(() -> System.out.println("Test"));
wrapper.add(() -> <something else>);
wrapper.add(() -> <something else>);
```

And later i can call it like:

`wrapper.get(0).execute();`

Is there any way using Function<?>

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can store a `List` of `Runnable` objects (if you don't need to return a value).

```
public class Wrapper {
    private final List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void add(Runnable r) {
        runnables.add(r);
    }
    
    public Runnable get(int index) {
        return runnables.get(index);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
        wrapper.add(() -> System.out.println("Test"));
        wrapper.get(0).run();
    }
}
```

If you want to return a value, you can use [`java.util.function.Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html).

```
public class Wrapper {
    private final List<Supplier<?>> suppliers = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void add(Supplier<?> s) {
        suppliers.add(s);
    }
    
    public Supplier<?> get(int index) {
        return suppliers.get(index);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
        wrapper.add(() -> "Test");
        System.out.println(wrapper.get(0).get());
    }
}
```

Comment: Just 1 question before accept. Runnable is creating a thread on each method i add. Is ther any other way to avoid that? Does it cost anything?

Comment: @Girlsarebeautiful Runnable doesn't create a Thread by itself.

Comment: @Girlsarebeautiful See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9029830/9513184

Comment: You can use Supplier<?>, if you don't want to take any argument, but return a value. You can use Consumer<?> instead of a Runnable, ignoring the argument: __ -> "do some work"

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use `Runnable` for semantic reasons, you could create your own functional interface.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Action {
    void execute();
}
```

Then, in your `Wrapper` class you'd have a method `add(Action action)`. Since the method signature is the same as in your example you can leave your code as is:

```
wrapper.add(() -> System.out.println("Test"));
```

And in the end you can call `wrapper.get(0).execute();` to call the wrapped method.

Comment: This is the "classic" way of implementing "function pointers" in Java (e.g. for callbacks).  Defining and implementing an interface (like in this example) is usually one of the *FIRST* design options I consider.  IMHO...